# Is it possible to disable the Flash plugin from a Chromium extension?

Tags: javascript, flash, google-chrome-extension

I know that it is possible to disable the Flash plugin in Chromium manually:

just go to chrome://plugins/, find "Adobe Flash Player" and disable it.

I was wondering if it is possible to disable Flash using JavaScript code or any client side Scripting language from an extension? And also, is there a way to communicate with other extensions such as FlashBlock, to dynamically update black/whitelists?

Comment: Do you mean as part of a regular page, or as part of an extension?

Comment: @minitech: I mean as a part of an extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is kind-of-yes, as long as you want to prevent flash plugin from loading, and not really disabling it globally.

The corresponding API is [`chrome.contentSettings`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSettings.html)

manifest.json:

```
"permissions": [ "contentSettings"]
```

Your script:

```
function blockFlash(block) {
  chrome.contentSettings.plugins.set({
    primaryPattern: '<all_urls>',
    resourceIdentifier: {
      id: 'adobe-flash-player'
    },
    setting: block ? 'block' : 'allow'
  });
}
```