# Enable/disable Chrome plugin from extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Is it possible to enable/disable a Chrome plugin from an extension?

My end goal is to write an extension that, for some specific plugin (in my case Flash), gives a one-click way to do the equivalent of going to `chrome://plugins`, finding the relevant plugin on the list, and clicking "enable" or "disable."

## Update 2

I have found that it ***is*** possible to achieve the desired result by entering the code  below into the JavaScript console on `chrome://plugins`. Now the **question** is how to do this in one click with an extension or bookmarklet. I'm keeping (a shortened form of) "update 1" after the code to show how I arrived at it.

To turn Flash **OFF**: `chrome.send('enablePlugin', ['/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/Versions/37.0.2062.94/Google Chrome Framework.framework/Internet Plug-Ins/PepperFlash/PepperFlashPlayer.plugin', String(false), String(false)]);`

To turn Flash **ON**: `chrome.send('enablePlugin', ['/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/Versions/37.0.2062.94/Google Chrome Framework.framework/Internet Plug-Ins/PepperFlash/PepperFlashPlayer.plugin', String(true), String(false)]);`

## Update 1

On the `chrome://plugins` page, there are event handlers in `plugins.js` that listen for clicks on the "enable" or "disable" links. Here's lines 123-139:

```
renderTemplate(pluginsData);

// Add handlers to dynamically created HTML elements.
var links = document.getElementsByClassName('disable-plugin-link');
for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
  links[i].onclick = function() {
    handleEnablePlugin(this, false, false);
    return false;
  };
}
links = document.getElementsByClassName('enable-plugin-link');
for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
  links[i].onclick = function() {
    handleEnablePlugin(this, true, false);
    return false;
  };
}
```

So this basically passes inputs to a universal plugin on/off function, which is in lines 192-203:

```
/**
 * Handles a 'enable' or 'disable' button getting clicked.
 * @param {HTMLElement} node The HTML element for the plugin being changed.
 * @param {boolean} enable Whether to enable or disable the plugin.
 * @param {boolean} isGroup True if we're enabling/disabling a plugin group,
 *     rather than a single plugin.
 */
function handleEnablePlugin(node, enable, isGroup) {
  // Tell the C++ PluginsDOMHandler to enable/disable the plugin.
  chrome.send('enablePlugin', [String(node.path), String(enable),
              String(isGroup)]);
}
```

Thanks to Developer Tools/"Inspect Element", it's clear what inputs to send to the function — `node.path` would be something like `/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/Versions/34.0.1847.137/Google Chrome Framework.framework/Internet Plug-Ins/PepperFlash/PepperFlashPlayer.plugin`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to disable the Flash plugin from a Chromium extension?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23275136/is-it-possible-to-disable-the-flash-plugin-from-a-chromium-extension)

Comment: Thanks @Xan, that seems like a decent workaround — but I'd love to figure out a way to actually enable/disable a plugin from an extension.

Comment: There is no API to do that, I'm afraid.

Comment: Commenting to clarify for others, since it's been a while: the linked question shows how to stop Flash (or some other plugin) from loading on a specific page; however, that implementation keeps the Flash plugin running. I've found that running Flash _even if_ it's not actually loaded slows down Chrome/my machine and makes crashes and other bad stuff much more common, so I keep Flash disabled except when actually using it. My goal is to stick with that solution, just to spend less time scrolling through `chrome://plugins`

Comment: I think you should make that comment a self-answer. You know, "impossible" is a valid answer, and it that later becomes possible, someone might add a better one.

Comment: I'm not sure that it is impossible, though. I know I can enable/disable the plugin via JavaScript from the console (see update 2). I don't know why, then, it would be impossible to write an extension or bookmarklet that would [a] open `chrome://plugins` and [b] run the script in one step for the user. Of course, there may be some security setting or something that makes it impossible, but I haven't yet found something that would prevent me from doing it — I just don't know how _to_ do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've written a fairly crude, but working, implementation in AppleScript. I'm still hoping to work out something more elegant and internal to Chrome.

Here's the script to turn Flash **ON**. To turn it off again, replace `true` with `false`.

*Edit: revised to stop the script from breaking every time Chrome updates its version. At this point I've been using this script for two months and it meets my needs. If someone has a nice, platform-independent way to implement this, though, I'd rather have that be the "answer."*

```
tell application "Google Chrome"
    activate
    open location "chrome://plugins"
    set myJS to "chrome.send('enablePlugin', ['/Applications/
        Google Chrome.app/Contents/Versions/" & version & 
        "/Google Chrome Framework.framework/Internet Plug-Ins/PepperFlash/
        PepperFlashPlayer.plugin', String(true), String(false)]);"
    delay 1
    tell window 1 to tell active tab
        execute javascript myJS
        close
    end tell
end tell
```